# Get the closed-form using jordan normal form?

Tags: matrices, closed-form

I have got the following transition matrix:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} p & 1-p \\ 1-q & q \end{pmatrix}$$

How can one use the jordan normal form to get a closed-form to calculate such a values $$A^n_{i,j}$$ ?

Comment: Did you try to compute the powers of a matrix in jordan normal form? What did you find?

Answer (score 1):

You find $P$ and $B$ such that $B$ is in Jordan form and $A=PBP^{-1}$. Then you find a formula for $A^n$ involving $B^n$, and take the advice of Rasmus from the comments.

Comment: I'll try. Thanks!